# How to change a card header color with a Select element, using Javascript, without affecting other cards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have more than one card, and inside each card, I have a Select element. A card header changes color when user chooses an option from the Select element; however, it changes all other card headers as well. How can I separate them?

```
    [data-background-color='empty'] {
      background-color: #595959;
      color: white;
    }

    [data-background-color='icu'] {
      background-color: #9933ff;
      color: white;
    }
    
    [data-background-color='med'] {
      background-color: #0066ff;
      color: white;
    }
```

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-background-color="empty">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="unitSelect">

        <option selected value="0">Empty</option>
        <option value="1">ICU</option>
        <option value="2">Med</option>
        
     </select>
     <!--some other content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#unitSelect').on('change', function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case '0':
      $('.card-header').attr('data-background-color', 'empty');
      break
    case '1':
      $('.card-header').attr('data-background-color', 'icu');
      break;
    case '2':
      $('.card-header').attr('data-background-color', 'med');
      break;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the selector `$('.card-header')` use the parent() of the select element that is being changed like `$(this).parent().attr('data-background-color', 'empty');`

This will only affect the .card-header of the select element being changed.

```js
$('.form-select').on('change', function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case '0':
      $(this).parent().attr('data-background-color', 'empty');
      break
    case '1':
      $(this).parent().attr('data-background-color', 'icu');
      break;
    case '2':
      $(this).parent().attr('data-background-color', 'med');
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
[data-background-color='empty'] {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: white;
}

[data-background-color='icu'] {
  background-color: #9933ff;
  color: white;
}

[data-background-color='med'] {
  background-color: #0066ff;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-background-color="empty">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="unitSelect">

      <option selected value="0">Empty</option>
      <option value="1">ICU</option>
      <option value="2">Med</option>

    </select>
    <!--some other content-->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-background-color="empty">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="unitSelect">

      <option selected value="0">Empty</option>
      <option value="1">ICU</option>
      <option value="2">Med</option>

    </select>
    <!--some other content-->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-background-color="empty">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="unitSelect">

      <option selected value="0">Empty</option>
      <option value="1">ICU</option>
      <option value="2">Med</option>

    </select>
    <!--some other content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nandita! Your suggestion worked as I needed.